# Insert date, Oracle 12, Flyway

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle-sqldeveloper, flyway

While setting up an existing project (thus I cannot change the scripts), the data migration fails on this line ;

```
insert into TABLE(NSQ, COD, TEXT, DAT_LAST) 
  values(1, 'EN', 'sample',to_timestamp('28-SEP-15 06.40.45.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM'));
```

With the error: 'ORA-1843', not a valid month.

Queries on the nls_session_parameters display the language as "american" and date format as "DD-MON-RR'.

What baffles me is that the insert is not working when run via flyway, but it succeeds without any problem when run in SQL Developer (same database).

Comment: Don't use language dependent date formats, best use ISO literals: `timestamp '2015-09-28 06:40:45'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Indeed, but I cannot change the scripts as it is an existing project I am getting into

Comment: maybe the `X` in the format mask i a problem? should not it  be a `.`?

Comment: Have you checked that the NLS settings are the same in Flyway as they are in SQL Developer? SQL Developer may set the session values to your user configuration when you connect to a new session whereas Flyway might be using the defaults.

Comment: @MT0 I have tried adding a script before all others that set the settings and now get ORA-1855 error, missing am/pm, which is weird because they are present

Comment: try with `alter session set nls_date_language=american;` before your scripts executes

Answer (score 1):

In your example the X in 'DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM' is a radix character (point).  Most systems recognize this as a separator between the integer SS and the fraction FF but apparently Flyway does not.  In oracle these 3 formats are functionally equivalent:
to_timestamp('28-SEP-15 06.40.45.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SSXFF AM')
to_timestamp('28-SEP-15 06.40.45.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM')
to_timestamp('28-SEP-15 06.40.45.000000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF9 AM')

Oracle Documentation:
Fractional seconds; no radix character is printed. Use the X format element to add the radix character. Use the numbers 1 to 9 after FF to specify the number of digits in the fractional second portion of the datetime value returned. If you do not specify a digit, then Oracle Database uses the precision specified for the datetime data type or the data type's default precision. Valid in timestamp and interval formats, but not in DATE formats.

Examples: 'HH:MI:SS.FF'

SELECT TO_CHAR(SYSTIMESTAMP, 'SS.FF3') from DUAL;
**End Oracle Documentation.
Unfortunately, it appears, you need to find someone who can change your code for compatibility purposes.